# Can I say a limit has a value of $\infty$?

Tags: limits, terminology

Can I say that limits like $\lim_{x\to\infty}x$ are equal to infinity?

E.g. the limit as $x\to+\infty$ of $x^2$ is infinity.

Is this a correct statement?

Sometimes my teacher says the above, sometimes they'd use the terms "inderterminate" or "undefined" also.

I wonder which is correct. Is it correct to say it's undefined?

Comment: The limit is infinite or equals infinity is commonly used for such limit:
$
\lim_{x\to \infty} x = \infty
$.
In contrast, we usually say that $\lim_{x\to 0} 1/x$ is undefined.

Comment: @Zubzub I disagree.

Comment: @Pedro with what statement? And what would you say instead?

Comment: @Zubzub You are completely right. In fact I completely agree with you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, **provided that the [right definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Infinite_limits) is given**.

The notation
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$$
is very common and acceptable. Well, the symbol $\infty$ is read as "infinity" so it is natural to say that a limit like that is infinite. **You only have to know what it means exactly and make it clear for the audience** (students, readers, etc.).

**The key point is to give a precise meaning for your terminology.** So, if you want call these limits "infinite", just put it in the definition. See for example how Apostol treat this topic:

[image]

Comment: Is it more correct to call it undefined or to call it infinity?

Comment: A new (with respect to the previous terminology) particular word can make a definition more appropriate, but it does not have the power of make it wrong. Most  (maybe all) authors refers to these kind of limits as "infinite limits". See for example section 7.15 in Apostol's book.

Comment: @theonlygusti See the edit in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Remember what limits mean. When I say that $f(x) \to f(c)$ as $x \to c$, I'm saying that I can make $f(x)$ as close to $f(c)$ as I want by making $x$ very close to $c$. When I say $f(x) \to c$ as $x \to \infty$ I'm saying that $f(x)$ can be made very close to $c$ by choosing $x$ sufficiently large.

An infinite limit means that as $x \to c$, $f(x)$ become arbitrarily large. I can make $f(x)$ as large as I want by choose $x$ sufficiently close to $c$. The notation $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \infty$ conveys this behavior and it's certainly well defined. Likewise, $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ means that as $x$ grows arbitrarily large, $f(x)$ becomes arbitrarily large. I can always make $f(x)$ larger by making $x$ larger. The notation $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ conveys this behavior and it's certainly well defined.

However, this notation does not treat $\infty$ as a number, but as a descriptor of behavior.

The reason why we don't say that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ is that the behavior of $\frac{1}{x}$ depends on the direction we approach $0$; approaching from the right makes this very large while approaching from the left makes it very small (negative numbers are small). Thus the limit is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Much of single variable calculus is most naturally set in the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). (and most of what is not is best set in the [real projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line))

- When the value of $x$ is taken to be in the reals, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x^2$ limit is undefined.
- When the value of $x$ is taken to be in the extended reals, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x^2$ exists and is equal to $+\infty$.

Note that in either case the domain of $x$ is taken to be in the extended reals, so that it makes sense to talk about $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Be careful. When you jump to the "extended reals" you need a metric in order to be able to talk about convergence. In particular, $d(x,y) = \left|x - y\right|$ would lead to problems; there is no sequence of real numbers that converges to $\infty$ under this metric.

Comment: @cgmil: Or the topological definition, such as the one in terms of a system of neighborhoods. In fact, the usual ad-hoc definition given in introductory calculus turns out to be exactly the the topological definition in terms of the system of neighborhoods $(x, +\infty]$ of $+\infty$ and $[-\infty, x)$ of $-\infty$.